# eclipse, dynamic web project, adding another eclipse project to classpath

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse dynamic web project that uses another project that contains all the business logic. I am able to get everything to run ok when I create a jar for the other project and add to WEB-INF/lib, but I would like to not do this.

In Java Build Path > Projects I have the project added, and in
Project References I also have it added.

Any other ideas? Did some searching and was not able to find the answer, thanks. 
bp

Comment: You want to make the business logic project be deployed by Eclipse when you run the web project on the configured server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add business project in deployment assembly of dynamic web project.

Steps:
Right Click on dynamic web project -> properties -> deployment assembly -> Add-> Project -> Select your project -> Finish

Redeploy your web application. This should work!